# Why does this htaccess rewrite rule fail?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Both this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule \.php$ /PHPTest/AB/index.php [L]
```

... and this one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php.*$
RewriteRule \.php.*$ /PHPTest/AB/index.php [L]
```

... result in this error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are generating `500 Internal Server Error` because you are causing infinite loop and when Apache runs out of Max redirect limit it returns 500 http code to the browser.

If you want to fix it then change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHPTest/AB/index\.php
RewriteRule \.php$ /PHPTest/AB/index.php [L]
```

Above `RewriteCond` will prevent execution after 1st time redirection to `/PHPTest/AB/index.php`